# error determining a generic return type in C++11

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, c++14, name-lookup

In the context of a C++14 application, I use a scheme which could be resumed as follows (minimal reproducible test):

```
template <class Container>
struct LocateFunctions {    
  auto get_it() const // <-- here is the problem
  {
    auto ret = typename Container::Iterator();
    return ret;
  }
};

template <typename T>
struct A : public LocateFunctions<A<T>> {    
  struct Iterator {};
};

int main() {  
  A<int> a;
}
```

This approach compiles and runs perfectly in C++14, with GCC and Clang compilers.

Now I want migrate my application to Windows and for that I'm using MinGW. Unfortunately, its latest version brings GCC 4.9 which does not compile C++14. That does not seem like a serious problem because I can rewrite the C++14 constructs in C++11. So, I rewrite the `get_it()` method as follows:

```
typename Container::Iterator get_it() const
{ 
  auto ret = typename Container::Iterator();
  return ret;
}
```

Unfortunately it does no compile. Both compilers produce the following error:

```
error: no type named ‘Iterator’ in ‘struct A<int>’
   typename Container::Iterator get_it() const
                            ^
```

I also tried:

```
auto get_it() const -> decltype(typename Container::Iterator())
{ 
  auto ret = typename Container::Iterator();
  return ret;
}
```

but I get exactly the same error.

Since two compilers fail to recognize the type of return, I suppose it is impossible to determine it. But I do not really know why.

Could someone please explain me why not compile and eventually a way for refactoring in C++11 that compiles?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You're using CRTP; `LocateFunctions` is instantiated with an incomplete specialization of `A` (`A<int>`), hence accessing that specialization's members gives the rather misleading error message ("no … named … in …" instead of "… is incomplete"). However, in your example **the function temploid `get_it` is only** (if ever) **instantiated after `A<int>` is indeed defined**, making the *typename-specifier* well-formed.

As for a workaround, try to achieve a similar effect, e.g. via

```
template <typename T=Container>
typename T::Iterator get_it() const
{
    static_assert(std::is_same<T, Container>{}, "You ain't supposed to supply T!");
    auto ret = typename T::Iterator();
    return ret;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/dHD4dTQYj1wezdD0) with GCC 4.9.

Comment: Temploid ? Is that a word ?

Comment: @Quentin Yes. It denotes non-template members of templates,  affected by a certain DR opened 15 years ago.

Comment: A big thank you Columbo for the explanation, workaround and edition

Comment: @lrleon Glad I could help :-)